# Template function to wrap any function passed to it in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use libgit2, and thought it would be nice to wrap the calls with something that will throw an exception for me instead.  My philosophy was that I would then be able to invoke functions that have a common return typ. I figured I would be able to do it with a templated function but I am running into some issues:

```cpp
template<typename F, typename... Args>
inline void invoke(Args&&... args) {
    git_error_code errCode = F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (errCode != GIT_OK) {
        throw GitErrorException(errCode);
    }
}
```

This generated some compiler warnings that I was not using a valid type so I figured that I could also use an alias instead:

```
template<typename ... Args>
using F = int (*)(Args&&... args);

template<F f, typename... Args>
inline void invoke(Args&&... args) {
    git_error_code errCode = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (errCode != GIT_OK) {
        throw GitErrorException(errCode);
    }
}
```

But that also did not work when using the code as follows:

```cpp
Git::invoke<git_branch_name>(&name, _ref);
```

Should I really have to rely on a macro instead here?

Comment: Maybe I'm too ignorant of the application, but how am I supposed to reproduce the errors you see?

Comment: You would usually pass `f` as function argument as well: `template<typename F, typename... Args>
inline void invoke(F f, Args&&... args)`. Then call `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` or to have it be more generic use `std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` instead of a direct call and maybe forward `f` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have following syntax

```
Git::invoke<git_branch_name>(&name, _ref);
```

You need (C++17)

```
template<auto F, typename... Args>
void invoke(Args&&... args) {
    git_error_code errCode = F(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (errCode != GIT_OK) {
        throw GitErrorException(errCode);
    }
}
```

For c++14, you might do instead

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F f, Args&&... args) {
    git_error_code errCode = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (errCode != GIT_OK) {
        throw GitErrorException(errCode);
    }
}
```

with usage

```
Git::invoke(&git_branch_name, &name, _ref);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I have not fully caught up with modern C++ yet, but its very cool to see new features like this.